# How to align two axes with CombinePlots?

Tags: plotting, graphics, functions, alignment

How can I align the lowest point and highest point of these two axes like 0 is aligned with 0 and 3 is aligned with 1.0 on the other axis?

The desired output is something like this (just to show the alignment and padding):

[image]

[image]

```
plot1 = Plot[x, {x, 0, 3}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Thick}, 
   LabelStyle -> Directive[Bold, 12, Black], ImagePadding -> True, 
   Frame -> {True, True, True, True}, 
   FrameStyle -> {Black, Red, Black, Transparent}, 
   GridLines -> {Range[0, 3, 0.2], Range[0, 3, 0.2]}];
plot2 = Plot[{x, 1/x}, {x, 0, 5}, 
   PlotStyle -> Directive[Blue, Thickness[0.01], CapForm["Round"]], 
   GridLines -> {Range[0, 3, 0.2], Range[0, 1, 0.2]}, 
   PlotRange -> {{0, 5}, {0, 1}}, ImagePadding -> True, 
   Frame -> {{True, False}, {True, True}}, 
   FrameStyle -> {{Directive[Blue, Thickness[0.005]], 
      ""}, {Directive[Black, Thickness[0.005]], ""}}];
ResourceFunction["CombinePlots"][plot1, plot2, "AxesSides" -> "TwoY"]
```

Comment: You could always play with PlotRange for plot2:                                               ```PlotRange -> {{0, 5}, {-0.055, 1.055}}```. This aligns the blue labels with the grid and has the advantage of showing the curves for x and 1/x crossing instead of appearing to be the same function.

Comment: @Jean-Pierre how would you get the number 0.055?

Comment: This is just trial and error increasing the range to compress the axis and go around the problem while maintaining these empty areas around the curves. A more standard appearance (eliminating empty areas) would be to set the PlotRange of plot1: ```PlotRange -> {{0, 3}, {0, 3}}```.

Comment: @Jean-Pierre how can I keep the empy area (padding) like your first method without trial and error? It looks simple but doesn't seem so.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Careful control of [`PlotRangePadding`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotRangePadding.html) gets you what you want:

```
plot1 = Plot[x, {x, 0, 3}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Thick}, 
   LabelStyle -> Directive[Bold, 12, Black], ImagePadding -> True, 
   Frame -> {True, True, True, True}, 
   FrameStyle -> {Black, Red, Black, Transparent}, 
   GridLines -> {Range[0, 3, 0.2], Range[0, 3, 0.2]}, 
   PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[0.05]];
plot2 = Plot[{x, 1/x}, {x, 0, 5}, 
   PlotStyle -> Directive[Blue, Thickness[0.01], CapForm["Round"]], 
   GridLines -> {Range[0, 3, 0.2], Range[0, 1, 0.2]}, 
   PlotRange -> {{0, 5}, {0, 1}}, ImagePadding -> True, 
   Frame -> {{True, False}, {True, True}}, 
   PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[0.05], 
   FrameStyle -> {{Directive[Blue, Thickness[0.005]], 
      ""}, {Directive[Black, Thickness[0.005]], ""}}];

ResourceFunction["CombinePlots"][plot1, plot2, "AxesSides" -> "TwoY", 
 PlotRangePadding -> None]
```

[image]

Note how I set `PlotRangePadding->Scaled[0.05]` for both plots. Using a scaled value like this makes sure that the ticks line up in the final plot, since the same fraction is used up by the padding on both sides. I also added `PlotRangePadding->None` to the `CombinePlots` call: This gets rid of some extraneous padding that is otherwise added. This is caused by a bug in `CombinePlots` and should not be necessary (I have submitted a fixed version, but it might take a while until it is approved).